# REST backend app script for doing CRUD transactions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy

As a side project, I am working on [Tiddly](https://github.com/prahladyeri/tiddly) which is a simple Python(Flask) based app for a generic REST backend that could be used for CRUD transactions on any kind of database (using `sqlalchemy`). I'd of course like if someone does a code review of it, especially the [app.py](https://github.com/prahladyeri/tiddly/blob/master/app.py) that contains the logic to select/insert/update/delete based on REST parameters:

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify, session
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import inspect, desc
import json
import models
from models import engine, dbsession

__author__ = "Prahlad Yeri"
__license__ = "MIT"
__credits__ = ["Prahlad Yeri"]
__version__ = "1.0.11"
__status__ = "Production"

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

#TODO: move this to a configuration file.
config = {
    'auth': False #enable authentication.
    }

def is_login_valid():
    return session.get('auth_email') != None

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
def index():
    return "It Works!"

@app.route("/_info")
def info():
    return jsonify({
        "Application": "flask-tiddly %s" % __version__,
        "Powered By": "flask %s, sqlalchemy %s" % (flask.__version__, sqlalchemy.__version__),
        })

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    data = json.loads(data)
    print('data:',data, type(data))
    query = dbsession.query(models.User).filter_by(email=data['email'], password=data['password'])
    rows = query.all()
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return jsonify({'status':'error', 'error':'Invalid email or password.'})
    else:
        session['auth_email'] = rows[0].email
        return jsonify({'status':'success'})

@app.route("/<table_name>", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "FETCH"])
def fetch(table_name):
    print("verb: %s, tablename: %s" % (request.method, table_name))
    if config['auth'] and not is_login_valid():
        print("Unauthorized Access.")
        return jsonify({
                "status": "error",
                "error": "Unauthorized Access."
            })
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            TableClass = models.get_class_by_tablename(table_name)
            if TableClass == None: raise Exception("Table not found: %s" % table_name)
            if id == None: #all data
                object = dbsession.query(TableClass).all()
                data = [object_as_dict(t) for t in object]
            else:
                object = dbsession.query(TableClass).filter_by(**{"id":id}).first()
                if object == None: raise Exception("No data found.")
                data = object_as_dict(object)
            return jsonify({
                "status": "success",
                "data": data
                })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({
                "status": "error",
                "error": str(e),
                })
    elif request.method == "POST" or request.method == "PUT":
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        print("data:", data)
        try:
            TableClass = models.get_class_by_tablename(table_name)
            if TableClass == None: raise Exception("Table not found: %s" % table_name)
            if request.method == "POST": #insert data
                object = TableClass(**data)
                dbsession.add(object)
                dbsession.commit()
            else: #update data
                object = dbsession.query(TableClass).filter_by(**{"id":id}).first()
                if object == None: raise Exception("No data found.")
                #object.update(**data)
                for key in data.keys():
                    setattr(object, key, data[key])
                #dbsession.add(object)
                dbsession.commit()
            return jsonify({
                "status": "success",
                "id": object.id,
                })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({
                "status": "error",
                "error": str(e),
                })
    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        try:
            TableClass = models.get_class_by_tablename(table_name)
            if TableClass == None: raise Exception("Table not found: %s" % table_name)
            object = dbsession.query(TableClass).filter_by(**{"id":id}).first()
            if object == None: raise Exception("No data found.")
            dbsession.delete(object)
            dbsession.commit()
            return jsonify({
                "status": "success",
                "id": object.id,
                })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({
                "status": "error",
                "error": str(e),
                })
    elif request.method == "FETCH":
        try:
            data = request.get_json(force=True)
            data = json.loads(data)
            print("data: ", data)
            print("data-type: ", type(data))
            TableClass = models.get_class_by_tablename(table_name)
            if TableClass == None: raise Exception("Table not found: %s" % table_name)

            query = dbsession.query(TableClass).filter_by(**data['where'])
            if 'orderby' in data:
                for cname in data['orderby'].split(','):
                    reverse = False
                    if cname.endswith(' desc'):
                        reverse = True
                        cname = cname[:-5]
                    elif cname.endswith(' asc'):
                        cname = cname[:-4]
                    print("cname: ", cname)
                    column = getattr(TableClass, cname)
                    if reverse: column = desc(column)
                    query = query.order_by(column)
            if 'limit' in data:
                query = query.limit(data['limit'])
                query = query.offset(data['offset'])
            object = query.all()
            data = [object_as_dict(t) for t in object]
            return jsonify({
                "status": "success", 
                "data": data
                })
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({
                "status": "error",
                "error": str(e),
                })
    else:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "error", "error": "Unrecognized verb.",
            })

def object_as_dict(obj):
    return {c.key: getattr(obj, c.key)
            for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("tiddly v%s" % __version__)
    app.secret_key = "4d5ert54fgcdf587ed5d"
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Secondly, I'd also like to know from someone who have worked on large open source projects, what kinds of unit test scenarios can I put in this app to ensure it doesn't break as I keep pushing code? Showing any actual techniques to implement unit tests in a python web app will of course be a bonus!

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, I'll modify the title.

Comment: @PrahladYeri it seems you missed the point about titles. I suggest to give another read to [ask]. In any case, I updated the title for you, I hope you get the idea.